# Make while loop print out multiple lists with csv.reader

Tags: list, python-2.7, csv, while-loop, repeat

I have a excel document filled with information i want my python code to print out. To give you guys an idea how my excel document looks like i will print out some code:

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open("n:\population.csv"))
print file.next()
```

This gives us the following output:

```
   ['country', 'country isocode', 'year', 'POP']
```

but this is not the part i want to print out, the relevant information is on the other lines, so if i enter one more print **file.next()** We get the following information:

```
['Netherlands', 'NLD', '1950', '10113.527']
```

This if the relevant infomation i need, now i only need to print out the year and the Population (POP), and do this for every line in my document. So i have come up with the following code to do this:

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open("population.csv"))
print file.next()


def print_population_list(filename):
    population_list_length = len("population.csv")
    number = 0
    line = file.next()
    while number < population_list_length:
        print line[2:]
        population_list_length = population_list_length - 1



print_population_list('N:\population.csv')
```

The problem is that the output of this code looks like:

```
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
['1950', '10113.527']
```

So how do i make my code print out the next line of my document instead of printing ut the same line over and over again until the number > population_list_length.

If someone could help me with this problem i would be so thankfull

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, one of the things you're not doing is advancing the line within the while loop (or in the for loop, for that matter).

You've defined line as file.next() but then tell it to print the part from the same line over and over.

Try this, taking note to advance the line at the end of each loop, after you've printed your data:

```
def print_population_list(filename):
    population_list_length = len("population.csv")
    number = 0
    line = file.next()
    while number < population_list_length:
        print line[2:]
        # the next line of code advances the line in the file
        line = file.next()
        population_list_length = population_list_length - 1

    # you don't need to advance the line here, 
    # as you've already advanced it at the end of the last loop

    for contry, isocode, year, population in 
        print line[2:]
        # the next line of code advances the line in the file
        line = file.next()
        population_list_length = population_list_length - 1
```